# jQuery keeps adding <li> tags to the dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Consider the following code:

```
$('#calendar-dates').on('click', 'td', function() {
   retrieve_availability(date, function(data) {       //ajax callback
        $appointments = data;

        window.appointments = $appointments;

        $(".appointments").hide().fadeIn();

        timetable();

        range($appointments);

      });
}

$('.appointments').on('click', 'li', function() {
    //do something

    $(".confirm").unbind().bind('click', function() {

    //do something
    }
}
```

and the html structure

```
<div class="appointments">
  <ul class="appointment_list">

    // <li> tags are appended dynamically

  </ul>
  <div class="actions">
    <a href="#" class="confirm">Apply</a>
    <a href="#" class="close">Cancel</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

What i want is when, the user clicks the confirm button, to close the whole appointments list. Because now everytime i click on the `<td>` element under the `#calendar-dates` the `<li>` tags get appended to the previously appended `<li>` tags

i need something of a reset

Comment: To delete the html inside the `ul` you could use - `$(".appointment_list").html("")`

Comment: This: `$(".confirm").unbind().bind('click', function() {` would appear to be better as a standalone `$(".actions").on('click', ".confirm", function() {`

Comment: Please clarify "close the whole appointments list" do you mean remove, replace, hide or some other specific action?

Comment: i mean remove its content.

Answer (score 0):

To remove content in an element, use .empty():

```
$(".appointment_list").empty();
```